# Black Rings Around Non-Emission Materials

Tags: rendering

I was experimenting with Freestyle, and at some point afterwards I noticed this weird reflection thing going on with anything that didn't have a material or had a BSDF shader.

[image]

The rings appear to be forming over a light source as well as some other light source (the background, maybe?)

[image]

Using the emission shader solves this problem, but using emission from the BSDF shader does not unless I turn its strength up very high (around 200). I can change the color of the material around things that aren't the black rings.

[image]

I was rendering this in Eevee. When trying things out in Cycles I got an error with the description "Failed to create CUDA context (Unknown error)" when I tried to render it with my graphics card but with just the CPU it works fine and does not appear to have this problem.

I used a plane for these images, but the problem applies to other objects as well.